# iphone keyboard not hiding when tapping the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, iframe

I have an input field with number type

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

In normal browsers, I'm typing some numbers and I'm tapping the screen, it hides iphone/ipad keyboard.

But this is not working if it is **inside iframe**. we need to click done button explicitly. **This issue is only for iphone/ipad**

This is an iframe issue. Any fix using Javascript/Jquery would be highly appreciated.

**Updated**

Tried

```
 document.activeElement.blur();
```

and focusout when event triggered in javascript. none of them are working..

```
   $(document).on('focusin', function(){
     $('input').css("background-color", "green");
      console.log('focusin!')
     });

  $(document).on('focusout', function(){
      console.log('focusout!')
     $('input').css("background-color", "yellow");
      $('input').blur();
     });
```

focusout is not calling inside iframe!

My question is `**How to force close ipad/iphone keypad when input element is not focused using Javascript/Jquery?**`

Answers will be rewarded as stated!

Comment: I've written a small plugin mainly for handling keyboard. It also supports hiding keyboard when clicking on document - excluding form components, which shouldn't trigger the hiding of keyboard.

Check code from here (L:70 - L:92): https://github.com/zvona/Servant.js/blob/master/Servant.js

Comment: wil check and let u know..

Answer (score 5):

To remove the keyboard you need to lose the focus on your input.

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

With this line you remove the focus and the keyboard disappear.

---

In your case, it's possible to add an event on your body, and stop this event if you click on an input.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('body').click(function () {
    document.activeElement.blur();
    console.log("blur");
  });

  $('input').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"/>
```

---

**Update**

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25420726/3083093) to get an active element into an iframe.

```
/**
 * Return the active element in the main web or iframes
 * @return HTMLElement
 **/
function getActiveElement() {
  var focused = false;

  // Check if the active element is in the main web or no
  if (document.body === document.activeElement ||
    document.activeElement instanceof HTMLIFrameElement) {

    // Search in iframes
    $('iframe').each(function() {
      var element = this.contentWindow.document.activeElement;
      // If there is a active element
      if (element !== this.contentWindow.document.body) {
        focused = element;
        return false; // Stop searching
      }
    });

  } else focused = document.activeElement;

  return focused; // Return element
}
```

With this function you can get the active element on the document or into an iframe.

After, you need to remove the focus on this element to hide the keyboard.

```
 getActiveElement().blur();
```

Comment: I tried ur code, When I click the input box, it disappears the keyboard and coudn't focus

Comment: Your input is into an iframe?

Comment: Inside iframe, I m calling a html which is in server...<iframe src="serverurl/index.html"></iframe>   In index.html, I m having input type

Comment: And you past the js code in index.html or in the parent page?

Answer (score 4):

html target `<input>` and `<textarea>`,  iphone and ipad will not hide keyboard when taping on blank area ;but android will! we need to hide keyboard by hand -- it means to set the input blur;

here gose the code

```
$(function(){

    var cacheInput = null;
    var timer = null;
    if(!isApple()){
        return false;
    }
    $(document).on('focus','input',function(e){
        cacheInput = e.target;
    })
    $(document).on('focus','textarea',function(e){
        cacheInput = e.target;
    })
    $(document).on('touchend',function(e){
        if(e.target.tagName!=='INPUT'&&e.target.tagName!=='TEXTAREA'){
            if(cacheInput!==null){
                timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    cacheInput.blur();
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                },300)
            }
        }
    })
    function isApple(){
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase();
        var 
          ipad = ua.indexOf('IPAD')>-1,
          ipod = ua.indexOf('IPOD')>-1,
          iphone = ua.indexOf('IPHONE')>-1 ;
        return   ipad || ipod || iphone ;
    }
})
```

github: https://github.com/wikieswan/iphone-input-blur

demo: http://wikieswan.github.io/iphone-input-blur

Comment: demo link is broken; but this seems to be the case for me too. works on android but not iphone. so this is just keeping track of input/textarea touches and then when any touch end event is called on any other element you know the focus should be shifted away from that input. pretty nice jQuery used here :) is there any official documentation to support that input/textarea blur doesnt work?

Answer (score 2):

In an ionic application I used a directive on the body that intercepts the inputs.

```
MyApp.directive('dismissIosKeyboardOnClick', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
          if (cordova.platformId=="ios") {
            element.on("touchstart", function(e) {
              var keyboardDoms = new Set(["INPUT","TEXTAREA","SELECT"]);
              if( keyboardDoms.has(document.activeElement.nodeName) &&
                  !keyboardDoms.has(e.target.nodeName) )
                document.activeElement.blur();
              });
            }
        };
      });
```

Index.html

```
<body ... dismiss-ios-keyboard-on-click></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this'll solve your issue, it simply removes the focus on active element.

- Using Javascript

> ```
>  document.activeElement.blur();
> ```

- Using jQuery

> ```
>  $("#Clicked_button_id").click(function() {
>     $("#input_field_id").blur();                               
> });
> ```

Comment: this is not working bro..when I m tapping input type, it closes the keyboard before entering any values

Comment: See ..http://jsfiddle.net/yaq3j9b9/  this is what happening..losing focus when tapping

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This detects when you tab any element but the input and then blurs it.

```js
$("html").children().not("#input_field_id").click(function(){
  $("#input_field_id").blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might possibly have a solution for your issue on iOS. My configuration is safari on iOS 8.3/5C.

From my experiments it seems to me that body element in Safari/iOS is not receptive to any click events. I am not able to explain why but it seems so.

So, what I have done is: put a wrapper div just inside body and allow it to receive the click.

**Main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>keyboard hide issue</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //!SOLUTION
        $('#body-wrapper').click(function(e) {
            console.log('I got clicked');
        });        
    });
</script>
<style>
/* ignore this. Its just styles. ... */
div#body-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
input {
    margin: 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="main-input1"/>
        <input type="number" id="main-input2"/>
        <input type="email" id="main-input3"/>
    </div>
    <iframe src="blur.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**blur.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Blur iFrame</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        //!SOLUTION
        $('#wrapper').click(function(e) {
            //do nothing 
        });        
    });
</script>
<style>
/* ignore this. Its just styles. ... */
div#wrapper {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" id="main-input"/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In both files I am able to hide the keyboard just fine. Again, I don't know the underlying reason but do let me know if you aren't able to replicate the solution.

I have not tried it on an iPad. Thanks ...

Comment: Won't work..This seems to be an iframe issue and cannot be fixed. Got fixed by reading charcode and did some hack

Answer (score 0):

Well... You can give me that reward cause I just solved this problem using a very ***SIMPLE*** solution.

**Step 1**
: 
Check if the input is currently in focus. I'll explain later why we need to add a delay on changing the value of `inputFocused` variable.

```
var inputFocused = false;
$('input').focus(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            inputFocused = true;
        },100);
    });
```

**Step 2:** Add an event listener if the screen or `$(window)` is tapped or clicked. If the window was tapped or clicked, check if the input is currently in focus. If **true** you must focus the window `$(window).focus()`, after focusing the window, the **blur()** function will now work! so you can now unfocus the input element then the keyboard will now hide automatically, then set the `inputFocused` variable to **false** again.

```
$(window).click(function(){
    if(inputFocused == true){
        $(window).focus();
        var input = $('input');
        input.blur();
        inputFocused = false;
    }
});`
```

**SetTimeout explanation:**
The `$(window).click()` event will trigger if the user tap or click anywhere on the screen (e.g. *Button click, Input click, tap or click screen, etc*). If you tap the input, at the same time setting the `inputFocused` to **true**, the `$(window).click()` event triggers then check if `inputFocused` is **true** then will run the code which hides the virtual keyboard. So it means that whenever you focus an input field the keyboard will hide and that'll be a problem.

That's why we're adding a delay so that the code inside `if(inputFocused == true)` will not run while we're focusing the input field and it will only run if the input field is currently on focus.

***TRIED AND TESTED!***