# Hide Textbox Keyboard when “Done / Return” Button is pressed Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive that will hide the keyboard when a user clicks the submit button in my app. The problem I am facing still is if someone clicks done or return, it will submit the form but will not hide the keyboard.

How could I implement something like this with my current directive?

**Directive**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('resonance.components.directives')
    .directive('touchSubmit', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        log('touchSubmit()');

        var textFields = element.find('input');
        element.bind('submit', function() {
            log('touchSubmit() > form was submitted');

            /* To dismiss onscreen keyboard */
            // In some cases, focus was needed before blur to dismiss onscreen keyboard
            textFields[0].focus();
            textFields[0].blur();

            /* To ensure status messages are visible on small screens */
            $window.scrollTo(0, 0);

      });
    };
  });

})();
```

Comment: I can't see your issue. Where have you seen that behavior? I've tested it on Android in FF and Chrome with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/btuL0seL/). The keyboard was always hiding (done click and with enter/open of keyboard). The `event.preventDefault()` in the demo is not really required.

Comment: I was testing it on an iphone 6. It would close the keyboard when i would hit the submit button. When i hit the return button in the iphone keyboard, it submitted the form but did not close the keyboard.

Comment: OK, sorry, can't test on iphone. Don't have one. Is the textfield still focussed after you hit the return button in the keyboard? Maybe the answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049222/iphone-keyboard-not-hiding-when-tapping-the-screen) helps.