# iframe: get active iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page with multiple iframes, at a time one one iframe is active, and i would like to know which iframe is active currently.

I tried `document.activeElement.id`, but it gives correct result only when I click on page some where.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420219/find-focused-element-in-document-with-many-iframes) also but not giving me active iframe id.

Do you know any javascript/jquery api to know active iframe id.

Comment: @vsync happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery you can try this:

```
var $focused = $(':focus');
```

The above will get the element that currently has focus.

Comment: @gavdix - how are you using it ?

Comment: I just used it in console as $(':focus') to see if it can track active iframe.