# Getting active element inside an iframe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, iframe

I am on a mission to find the active element inside of an iframe.

This is the code that works if the current document was not an iframe

```
public componentWillMount(): void {
this._originalFocusedElement = getDocument()!.activeElement as HTMLElement;  }
```

For an iframe, I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420219/find-focused-element-in-document-with-many-iframes) stack overflow post, and tried to use it in my code as follows

```
public componentWillMount(): void {
this._originalFocusedElement = getDocument()!.contentWindow.document.activeElement;
}
```

However, this does not compile.

Any guidance on how I can find the active element inside of the iframe would be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find focused element in document with many iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420219/find-focused-element-in-document-with-many-iframes)

Answer (score 0):

> However, this does not compile

Assuming this compiles :

```
this._originalFocusedElement = getDocument()!.activeElement as HTMLElement;
```

You are missing `as HTMLElement` in the code that doesn't compile.

## Fixed Code

```
this._originalFocusedElement = getDocument()!.contentWindow.document.activeElement as HTMLElement;
```

Comment: The first one compiles, however, the second one gives me, "[ts] Property 'contentWindow' does not exist on type 'Document'."